# pass an array as key in a wordpress function as for example get_post_meta

Tags: wordpress

this is a simple get_post_meta function:

```
<?php $key_1_values = get_post_meta( 76, 'key_1' ); ?>
```

Its return the value of key 'key_1'.

But if i want the values of multiple keys, 'key_1', 'key_2', etc..), is it possible pass an array as key or use special chars ?

for example:

```
<?php $key_1_values = get_post_meta( 76, array('key_1','key_2','key_3') ); ?>
```

And is it possibile get values of all keys that starts with a string ?

for example:

```
<?php $key_1_values = get_post_meta( 76, 'key_%' ); ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: [no, it's not.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

Comment: It's not, but you may have some options. Do all of your keys follow the same naming convention? And do they all end with a number? Is there an upper limit?

Answer (score 0):

According [to the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) it is not possible, key has to be a string.

But you can wrap this easily in your own function:

```
// getting multiple meta values
function get_post_meta_array($post, $keys) {
  $return = array();
  foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $return[$key] = get_post_meta($post, $key);
  }
  return $return;
}
```

To get all values with a prefix you can use `get_post_custom()` to fetch all fields of a post, then filter through the keys.